# How to map invalid user input with last value in enum list?

Tags: c++, input, enums

I have a basic `enum` declaration:

```
enum Title {Prof, Dr, Mr, Mdm, Mrs, Miss, NA};
```

I've managed to map the user input from `0` to `5` with value from enum list respectively:

```
std::map<std::string,Title> m;
m["0"] = Prof;
m["1"] = Dr;
m["2"] = Mr;
m["3"] = Mdm;
m["4"] = Mrs;
m["5"] = Miss;
m[???] = NA; // What should I do here    

std::string stitle;

cout << "\n" << "Title (0:Prof 1:Dr 2:Mr 3:Mdm 4:Mrs 5:Miss Any:NA): ";
cin >> stitle;
Title title = m[stitle];
```

How can I map the user input such as `6`, `7` or any input beside `0` to `5` with `NA` value from the enum list?

Comment: Did you create a new account to circumvent a question ban?

Comment: No, this question is absolutely different from your mentioned question so there is no reason for you to mark this question as duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You can just use `find`, instead of `operator []`.

```
std::map<std::string, Title>::iterator pos = m.find(stitle);
Title title = pos == m.end() ? NA : pos->second;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask what's the meaning of `pos->second` here?

Comment: @Pewds std::map stores pairs, so, pos->second actually means (*pos).second, that means dereference iterator, get pair and get second element from pair.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `operator[]`, which will implicitly add an entry for a key if it does not exist, I would use `at`, which throws an exception instead:

```
Title title;
try {
    title = m.at(stitle);
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    title = NA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like

```
if(m.find(stitle) == m.end()) { cout << "Invalid input" << endl; //Exit here or loop again? }
else
  Title title = m[stitle];
```